# PHP processing tab delimited txt line by line progress/status bar

Tags: php, file, progress-bar, file-read

I have an import module, I have to process a Tab delimited txt file line by line. The problem is that the file could have above 250K lines. I have to make a SELECT and an UPDATE or INSERT operation in MySQL database. This could get up to 3-4 hours of work for the server.
I would like to put a status bar which shows where are we at in the processing. I have tried just updating an input when processing the lines of the file, but the browser could not really output it, it just froze. How could I output the status of the processing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this asynchronously, since otherwise the connection from browser to the server will time out.

You can create another table in the DB to hold the progress of the processing of the file - you can update a record in that table every 100 or 1000 lines processed.

On the client side, you can update that progress bar in javascript by interogating the backend and get values from that progress table.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good. if I do that with jQuery AJAX, will it output it for me?

Comment: yes ... I recommend you to start a background process that will process the large file

Answer (score 0):

Maype a simple flush() will do the job:

```
// ...

$done++
if ( ($done % 1000) == 0 ) {
    print "$done of $total lines processed<br />";
    flush();
}

// ...
```

If your using a Windows-Server, you might have a look at the comments of the doc page, there seem to be some quirks: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php